# Find the focused element in end-to-end test for Stencil component

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing, stenciljs

How can I check which element has focus in a Stencil test? I can't use `document.activeElement` like I would normally do, as it always returns `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
const activeElId = await page.evaluate(() => document.activeElement!.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stencil components use Shadow DOM by default and that means that if some element in the Shadow DOM is in focus you can't get it through the normal `document.activeElement` property. On the other hand, the Shadow DOM host element includes an `activeElement` property as well (the host element is handled as a different document). You can use the host's `activeElement` property in your tests, which should hold the focused element inside the Shadow DOM. You can read about that property in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement). 
In some of my projects, when an element is getting focus I add a class to it which helps me to query it later and to add focus styles. This is another way to find elements which are in focus (query for the class).

Comment: Not a shadow DOM issue, `document.activeElement` works fine elsewhere, but returns `undefined` for tests. The mock `document` used by the test suite doesn't seem to have an `activeElement` property...

Comment: If that is the case, it sounds like a missing feature in Stencil Puppeteer abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and agree with Gil Fink that it seems to be missing from the Stencil Puppeteer abstraction.

I've worked round it by checking that the id of the [active element of my components shadow root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) is the same as the id of the element I expect to have focus. I retrieved the id of the active element using [Puppetteers `page.$eval(...)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), e.g.:

```
const activeElementId = await page.$eval('my-component', (el) => el.shadowRoot.activeElement.id);

const elementThatShouldBeActive = await page.find('my-component >>> #some-id');

expect(activeElementId).toEqual(elementThatShouldBeActive.id);
```

That works for my context, hopefully it's helpful for you too.